# Usar "ping" em um site com Python

Tags: python

No CMD do Windows é possível usar o comando `ping` para pegar o IP de determinados sites, por exemplo:

```
ping www.facebook.com.br
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer algo semelhante usando o Python 3.4?

Comment: Se você quiser uma implementação do comando PING em python usando apenas socket, pode encontrar nesse link aqui : http://www.g-loaded.eu/2009/10/30/python-ping/ Infelizmente, para o propósito desse site, está em inglês. Usei no passado e funcionou para mim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumo que seja no windows, certo? Isso serve, acho, nao tenho como testar. Tirei [daqui](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html).

```
from subprocess import check_output
check_output("ping www.facebook.com", shell=True)
```

Comment: Complementando que seria possível implementar ping (ICMP) dentro do próprio programa, sem invocar um shell externo, mas tal programa precisa ter permissões de root ou administrador, então acaba sendo mais interessante usar o ping preexistente mesmo.

Comment: Só não sei porque usar `shell=True` - você pode evitar a invocação do shell assim `check_output(["ping", endereco])` dessa forma menos um processo é executado, gastando menos recursos e tempo.

Answer (score 5):

No Linux, já dentro da *shell* do Python 3.2.3,  basta simplesmente: :

```
import subprocess

a=subprocess.Popen("ping -c4 www.boadica.com.br", shell=True)
```

Deve dar certo tb no Windows

Comment: Só não sei porque usar `shell=True` - você pode evitar a invocação do shell assim `check_output(["ping", "-c4", endereco])` dessa forma menos um processo é executado, gastando menos recursos e tempo.